# Stub telephone input jest vue JS

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I'm trying to stub a tel input plugin I'm using in one of my Vue component.

This is what I've tried, I think I almost got it but I'm missing one small detail.

This is my spec file:

```
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import ModalNewCustomer from "../../../resources/js/subviews/customers/components/ModalNewCustomer";

// Stubs
const telInput = {
    template: `<input type="tel">`
}

import moment from 'moment';

describe('Modal New Customer',() => {
    let wrapper,mockCheckNameDuplicate;

    let districts = [
        {"id":1,"name":"Aberdeen"},
        {"id":2,"name":"Admiralty"},
        {"id":3,"name":"Ap Lei Chau"},
        {"id":4,"name":"Beacon Hill"},
        {"id":5,"name":"Braemar Hill"},
        {"id":6,"name":"Causeway Bay"},
        {"id":8,"name":"Central"}
    ];

    let newCustomerData ={
        firstName: 'Loulou',
        lastName: 'Le Loup',
        emailAddress: 'email@google.com',
        sex: 'M',
        primaryPhoneNumber: '+85200001111',
        secondaryPhoneNumber: '+85233334444',
        birthday: "2020-11-30",
        wayOfContact: 'email',
        electroOrNot: 1,
        asiaMilesMembership: '00001111'
    };

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockCheckNameDuplicate = jest.spyOn(ModalNewCustomer.methods, 'checkNameDuplicate');

        wrapper = mount(ModalNewCustomer,{
            localVue,
            propsData:{
                districts: districts
            },
            data(){
                return{
                    COMPANY_NAME: 'HK'
                }
            },
            router,
            stubs:{
                "vue-tel-input": telInput
            }
        });

        flushPromises();
        jest.resetModules();
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        flushPromises();
        jest.resetModules();
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    })

    it('can input new customer data and submit it',async() => {
        const {vm} = wrapper;

        let primaryPhoneNumberInput = wrapper.find('#primaryPhoneNumber');
        await primaryPhoneNumberInput.setValue(newCustomerData.primaryPhoneNumber)

        expect(primaryPhoneNumberInput.element.value).toBe(newCustomerData.primaryPhoneNumber);
        console.log(primaryPhoneNumberInput.html())
        console.log(vm.newCustomer.primaryPhoneNumber)


    });
});
```

In my vue component, the vue tel input looks like this:

```
             <vue-tel-input
                 id="primaryPhoneNumber"
                 :default-country="COMPANY_NAME"
                 validCharactersOnly
                 v-model="newCustomer.primaryPhoneNumber"
                 :inputOptions="inputOptions">
             </vue-tel-input>
```

The problem is when I set the value of my stub component, the data of the Vue component I'm testing is not being updated, when it should be rerendered thanks to v-model.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe try to use ref instead of id
And then find the component with 

wrapper.findComponent({ref: 'primaryPhoneNumber'})

You can see here more details about how to test custom input component
https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#interacting-with-vue-component-inputs

Comment: Thanks for your insights. However using refs is not enough:

If I set the value like this:         await wrapper.findComponent({ref:"primaryPhoneNumber"}).setValue(editedCustomer.primary_phone_number)

The vue data is not updated..

Any idea ?